# How can I trigger the change event of a select, if I have many in the view? (vue and v-select)

Tags: vue.js, select, view, v-select

I am showing the following view, where I have a list of selects to be able to select the desired program, but the @change event of the v-select is not firing, it only works with a normal select, but I do not use a normal select because I need the search functionality that v-select provides, any ideas how to make the @change event work?

**Code from view**

> <v-select     :id="`selectPs${item['id']}`"    label="name"
> :options="programsToSelect"    @change="signalChangeProgram($event,
> item['
>
> > 

**view**

[image]

Comment: Crunch idea: V-select is wrapper around pure html select item. You can add ref to this component, find native html select and every time native select changes value you can emit from v-select component change event

Comment: Good idea: if v-select is your own custom component, do the same as I mentioned above without crunch. If it's not your custom element open vue devtools and look which event v-select emits